# Replace Contact name address book

Tags: ios4, addressbook

Can we replace contacts name from native application? For example a record is already saved in contact with name "abc" and i have to change it with name "xyz". Now record should be replaced with name "xyz" in address book. Please give me any small hint so that i can start work on it. Help would be appropriated in advance. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can delete old one and save new one.

Comment: Why is this tagged `iOS4`? There is no reason at all to be supporting iOS 4 anymore. iOS 7 came out today.